# retreive only keys from deeply nested Json response in Groovy

Tags: json, dictionary, groovy, jmeter

I have a deeply nested json and I'm able to retrieve the keys of first three levels now I have a third level,and accessing like this (checks.payments.paymentToItems)) to a variable, values of a variable are printed as below like this

`[[[[id:check, declaredAmount:13.74, paidAmount:13.74, timestamp:2020-06-24 06:51:11.084276+00:00], [id:tip, declaredAmount:2.15, paidAmount:2.15, timestamp:2020-06-24 06:51:11.084276+00:00]]], [[[id:check, declaredAmount:13.74, paidAmount:13.74, timestamp:2020-06-24 06:57:34.090822+00:00], [id:tip, declaredAmount:2.15, paidAmount:2.15, timestamp:2020-06-24 06:57:34.090822+00:00]]], [[[id:check, declaredAmount:13.74, paidAmount:13.74, timestamp:2020-06-24 07:02:24.829866+00:00], [id:tip, declaredAmount:2.15, paidAmount:2.15, timestamp:2020-06-24 07:02:24.829866+00:00]]], [[[id:check, declaredAmount:13.74, paidAmount:13.74, timestamp:2020-06-24 07:04:23.192466+00:00], [id:tip, declaredAmount:2.15, paidAmount:2.15, timestamp:2020-06-24 07:04:23.192466+00:00]]], [[[id:check, declaredAmount:13.74, paidAmount:13.74, timestamp:2020-06-24 07:08:23.481073+00:00], [id:tip, declaredAmount:2.15, paidAmount:2.15, timestamp:2020-06-24 07:08:23.481073+00:00]]], [[[id:check, declaredAmount:13.74, paidAmount:13.74, timestamp:2020-06-24 09:51:38.040312+00:00], [id:tip, declaredAmount:2.15, paidAmount:2.15, timestamp:2020-06-24 09:51:38.040312+00:00]]], [[[id:check, declaredAmount:13.74, paidAmount:13.74, timestamp:2020-06-24 09:53:59.884796+00:00], [id:tip, declaredAmount:2.15, paidAmount:2.15, timestamp:2020-06-24 09:53:59.884796+00:00]]]]`

now I want to retrieve only keys and add to list for validating each field.
I have tried below approach as the map starts with four square brackets [[[[ but getting only null values
can someone please throw light on this.

````
        log.info("-----------------------payments $paymentToItems");
        def lstKeys=[]
        //taxMap.each { entry -> lstKeys.add( $entry.key") }
        
        for (entry in paymentToItems) {
             
             def map =entry
             for(entry2 in map){
             log.info("-----------------------paymentkeys $lstKeys");
                def finalMap =entry2 
                for(entry3 in finalMap){
                    def lasMap = entry3
                //for(entry4 in lasMap)
                    def key=entry3.key 
                        lstKeys.add(key)
                    
                }
                
             }
             
            log.info("-----------------------paymentkeys $lstKeys");
        } ```

$lstKeys keys print null values

2020-06-25 01:58:11,356 INFO o.a.j.a.J.JSR223 Assertion: -----------------------paymentkeys [null, null]
2020-06-25 01:58:11,357 INFO o.a.j.a.J.JSR223 Assertion: -----------------------paymentkeys [null, null, null, null]
2020-06-25 01:58:11,357 INFO o.a.j.a.J.JSR223 Assertion: -----------------------paymentkeys [null, null, null, null, null, null]
2020-06-25 01:58:11,357 INFO o.a.j.a.J.JSR223 Assertion: -----------------------paymentkeys [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
2020-06-25 01:58:11,357 INFO o.a.j.a.J.JSR223 Assertion: -----------------------paymentkeys [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
2020-06-25 01:58:11,357 INFO o.a.j.a.J.JSR223 Assertion: -----------------------paymentkeys [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
````

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure, what kind of beast your are fighting, bring the
data you have into a structured, hierarchical form:

```
def data = [ /*1*/
    [ /*2*/ [ /*3*/
        [id:'check', declaredAmount:13.74, paidAmount:13.74, timestamp:'2020-06-24 06:51:11.084276+00:00'],
        [id:'tip',   declaredAmount:2.15,  paidAmount:2.15,  timestamp:'2020-06-24 06:51:11.084276+00:00']
    ]], 
    [[
        [id:'check', declaredAmount:13.74, paidAmount:13.74, timestamp:'2020-06-24 06:57:34.090822+00:00'],
        [id:'tip',   declaredAmount:2.15,  paidAmount:2.15,  timestamp:'2020-06-24 06:57:34.090822+00:00']
    ]] 
    // ...
]
```

So your data is

1. a list of
2. lists with just a single
3. list of maps

So your biggest "problem" here is the useless #2.  You can get rid of
that via e.g. `.first()` while navigating.  E.g.

```
data.each{
    it.first().each{
        println it.id
    }
}
```

Or you should rather take care **not** to create such a problem in the
first place.  Make sure you are structuring your data properly upstream
already instead of battling inconveniences likes that from there on
after.

Note: The regular `.toString()` from groovy is just useful for a quick
read, but not useful to share with others.  Given you only have simple
data, use `.inspect()` to get something, that others can use.  E.g.
`println data.inspect()`